# Updating Account Fields without Hard Coding Values

Tags: apex

In most tutorials, I notice that they usually hard code field values when updating Account or other objects, like these:

```
 List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 5];

 for(Account acc : acctList) {
     acc.Name = 'Sample 1';
 }
 update acctList;
```

Is there any way I can update field values without hard coding values?

Comment: You can certainly assign a value from a variable that holds a value from some other object or a calculated value. Adding more information to your question about what your problem is would help here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. In tutorial they use hardcoded value so that new developer can easily understand the code and it seasy to copy paste this code in your org and can play with it.

Some of example using dynamic value

Add dynamic count in end

```
List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 5];
Integer count =1;
 for(Account acc : acctList) {
     acc.Name = 'Sample '+count;
     count++;
 }
 update acctList;
```

get inputs from user and then pass it in field

```
   string userInputName{get;set;}
   List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 5];

     for(Account acc : acctList) {
         acc.Name = userInputName;

     }
     update acctList;
```

Pass or select name from another Account record

```
List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 5];

         for(Account acc : acctList) {
             acc.Name = Account.name;  //account is instance of another account record you can use any sobject here

         }
         update acctList;
```